# Writing syncopes in harmonic grids

Tags: notation, beats, syncopation

I am learning how to write [a harmonic grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_chart) and I wondered how to write a syncope?

I thought about doing:

[image]

If that makes sense? Is it the standard notation?

Comment: I can't find an example of this outside of the link given in the post, nor can I find any reference to it outside the post. That said, I find the syncope notation you suggest ambiguous. Does it mean one chord should either be held over into the next bar, or anticipated in the previous bar? If yes, then adding an arrow at one end of the arc would be helpful to know which.

Comment: @Aaron This notation is very similar to the iRealPro app, which I've seen some jazz musicians use on gigs.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this type of notation does not allow for this level of specificity, so this certainly isn't standard. These charts assume the performer is already familiar with the song, and the chord chart is just meant to jog the player's memory.

That being said, it is not uncommon for musicians to come up with their own symbols and notations to serve their own purposes. So, if it helps you, feel free to keep using it, but if you are giving this music to other performers they might not understand.